# Kafka Integration with Salesforce

Tags: csv, apache-kafka, salesforce, sftp

We have to read CSV file from SFTP server/folder and with the help of Kafka I have to  push this data into Salesforce Sobject .Similarly we have to read any Sboject Data from salesforce and convert this data into into CSV file and send to SFTP server.
Can you please give me some idea about that ?How i can achieve this?

Comment: Kafka doesn't push data. It's the responsibility of a client to pull from Kafka

Answer (score 0):

i did not check it very careful but maybe you can have a reading for this ,if you could query data from salesforce then you can change it to any formats.
[Salesforce Connector (Source and Sink) for Confluent Platform — Confluent Platform](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-salesforce/index.html)
[Salesforce Platform Events Sink Connector for Confluent Platform — Confluent Platform](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-salesforce/platformevents_sink/index.html)